# Ionic 3 :If this is a project you'd like to integrate with Ionic, create an ionic.config.json file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

I'm working with Ionic3: (version 4 is Beta yet)

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v8.13.0
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Linux 4.13
```

And I try to run a confirmed project from github (320 stars), so the npm i goes OK, but When I try to run the App I've got a strange Error:

```
ionic cordova run android
[ERROR] Sorry! ionic cordova run can only be run in an Ionic project directory.

        If this is a project you'd like to integrate with Ionic, create an 
        ionic.config.json file.
```

So What Should I do ? if I have to create a file as recommended what I will put into it ?

Comment: I assume the project has an ionic.config.json file associated with the project. Make sure you're in the right directory. If so, then you may have to create a blank template Ionic project first using ionic start. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/

Comment: Yes Sorry, it was just an Ionic cordova plugin and not an ionic project, Sorry!!!